# Содержит ли строка один из элементов массива

Tags: python

Есть переменная
`a="Саша"`
и есть массив
`b=['Саша', 'Миша', 'Настя', 'Костя']`

как можно проверить, есть ли имя Саша в массиве `b`?

Comment: `a in b`.......

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вы неправильно определили список

```
if a in b:
    pass
```

Comment: а вот если у меня вызывается скрипт с параметрами main.py Саша Миша Маша Настя то как в таком случае быть? if a in sys.argv ?

Comment: попробуйте вместо sys используйте main

Comment: @Mark, какой `main`? Все аргументы передаются в `sys.argv`, так что ответ на вопрос @user0987 - да

Comment: @user0987 `if a in sys.argv[1:]:`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "саша"
b = ["саша", "миша"]
for k in b: 
    if k == a: print("Нашёл")
```

Comment: Не, неоптимально. Посмотрите соседний ответ.